# Difference between mvn appengine:update and mvn appengine:deploy in Google App Engine

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, maven-3

What is the difference between 
`mvn appengine:update` 
and 
`mvn appengine:deploy` in Google App Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the configuration you're using for your project. The [old AppEngine plugin for Maven](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-maven-plugin) only supports `mvn appengine:update` as far as I know. The [newer one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin) supports `mvn appengine:deploy`.

By the way, the [very latest one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-maven-plugin) was renamed to `mvn gcloud:deploy`, so that might add to the confusion.

Comment: The very latest one is not the link provided if you follow that link you will notice it is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

According to the google app engine reference:

For `mvn appengine:deploy`

> The appengine:deploy goal and all other goals in the App Engine Maven
>   plugin have associated parameters that you can use. For a complete
>   list of goals and parameters, refer to App Engine Maven Plugin Goals
>   and Parameters.

[The complete reference here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/using-maven)

For `mvn appengine:update` :

> To deploy your app with Maven, run the following command from your
>   project's top level directory, where the pom.xml file is located, for
>   example:
>
> mvn appengine:update

[The complete reference here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp)